# Create chart in odoo 10.0

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create a bar chart (graph view) in odoo 10 that can display the number of students studying in each course. With this python database, how can I implement it ? There are no sample codes about this type of view on the Internet.

```
class Student(models.Model):
   _name = "studentmanagement.student"

   id= fields.Char(required=True, index=True)
   full_name= fields.Char(required=True, index=True)
   gender = fields.Char()
   birthday = fields.Char(required=True)
   address = fields.Char(required=True)
   course_inscription = fields.Many2many('studentmanagement.course',string = 'inscription')
   _sql_constraints = [('id_unique', 'UNIQUE(id)', 'Two students can not have the same ID!')]


class course(models.Model):
     _name = "studentmanagement.course"

     code = fields.Char(required=True, index=True)
     course_name = fields.Char(required=True, index=True)
     credits = fields.Integer(required=True)
     nstudent= fields.Integer(compute='_compute_percentage_students_course', store=True)
     _sql_constraints = [('code_unique', 'UNIQUE(code)', 'Two courses can not have the same ID!')]

     @api.depends('percentage','course_inscription')
     def _compute_percentage_students_course(self):
        for record in self:
            record.nstudent = len(record.course_inscription)
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph view:

```
<graph string="Sales Orders">
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <field name="amount_total" type="measure"/>
</graph>
```

That graph view has two fields. Depending on the type of the chart they will be rendered accordingly.

You have to create a field that will will hold the calculated percentage like:

`percentage = fields.Float(compute='_compute_percentage_students_course' store=True)`

Within that `_compute_percentage_students_course` you will calculate and set the calculation to be the value of the `percentage` field (check the Computed fields section on the official [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html) on how to properly create a computed field)

Also, check the [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#graphs) on the graph views that tells you how a graph is created, the types of graphs you can have etc. The below should work for you:

```
<graph string="Sales Orders">
                        <field name="full_name"/>
                        <field name="percentage" type="measure"/>
    </graph>
```

Comment: def _compute_percentage_students_course(self):
     for r in self:
          nostudent = len(r.course_inscription)
          r.percentage = nostudent / 100 It does not work, in other view of course forms, all of its perceantages are 0 !

Comment: The graph view works if the computed fields are stored. So make sure that you put a `store=True` on the definition of your computed field.

Comment: It works, thanks alot =]]. I forgot to turn on the "developer mode" and reinstall the odoo